# Detect when an observable has emitted the same value twice in a row

Tags: node.js, websocket, rxjs, timeout, observable

I'm using a keep-alive mechanism to my websocket connection with the method from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42120267/7360914):

```
Observable.timer(0, 5000)
  .map(i => 'ping')
  .concatMap(val => {
    return Observable.race(
      Observable.of('timeout').delay(3000),
      sendMockPing()
    );
  })
```

If a timeout happens I need to completely reset the websocket connection (as it likely means the connection is broken), but sometimes a single timeout can just happen randomly (due to a poor server implementation I guess?)

My subscription logic is currently implemented like this

```
).subscribe(result => {
  if (result === 'timeout') {
    // Reconnect to server
  }
}
```

Is there any way (preferably using RxJs) to map the observable in a way so I can recognize the case where it has emitted `'timeout'` twice in a row?

Comment: If you're only interested in *ignoring* two similar events, you can also take advantage of the [distinctUntilChanged](https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/filtering/distinctuntilchanged.html) operator

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the [`scan`](https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/api/operators/scan) operator to do what you want:

```
source.pipe(
  scan((previous, next) => {
    if ((previous === 'timeout') && (next === 'timeout')) {
      throw new Error('Two consecutive timeouts occurred.');
    }
    return next;
  }, undefined);
);
```